# php: how can I handle telegram bot request error?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I use this: https://telegram-bot-sdk.readme.io/docs

```
$response = $telegram->sendMessage([
        'chat_id' => '@username', 
        'text' => 'Hello World'
]);
```

when the username is true, it works. but how can I handle errors? for example when username is wrong or not exist.

Comment: How your $response looks? Do you have a response code? Please show us a response structure

Answer (score 0):

> 1-Some people does not have username!(you can have telegram account with just first name and valid phone number)
>
> 2-You cannot send to any valid username(Your bot can just send to users subscribed to your bot (open a chat at least once) and not blocked afterwards)
>
> 3-By telegram you can just send to users by [`chat_id`( a large unique number)](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chat) and not by `@username` .